# Typogrify Line Breaks (Chrome)

Tags: plugin-typogrify

I've moved from Wordsmith to Typogrify because of the additional config options, which are great. I am having an issue though with line breaks appearing in

tags in Chrome in very specific cases. I have hyphenation turned off.

Link here:
https://thecinematheque.ca/films/2021/film-about-a-father-who

Break added after "Film About a Father Who" when window is around 720px wide. No idea if this is a CSS issue but I cant see anything that would cause that.

I do see a `&#8203;` element added near by. Not sure where that is coming from.

​​​​​​​

Answer (score 1):

They both use the same underlying library, so things like this should be identical in both of them. But there was a recent GH issue that might answer this for you: https://github.com/nystudio107/craft-typogrify/issues/33